# Two tab bar items with one view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbaritem

I really need your help. I know that what my question contains not so good UI practices, but I need to do it...

In my app I have `TabBarController` with four items. The first item is "Channel" item, the third item is "Search" item. So, when users selecta "Search" item, I need show him "Channel" and searching something in `ChannelViewController`. I want that "Channel" and "Search" items have only one view controller - `ChannelViewController`.

I can present ChannelViewController, but then TabBar navigation isn't showing. I've written this code in `SearchViewController`:

```
    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {

        let channelViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("channelViewController") as! ChannelViewController
        self.presentViewController(channelViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }
```

Can I do this without `SearchViewController`? Can I just add or show/hide when I select "Search" item?

Is it possible do something like this:

```
override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {     
    if tabBar.items?.indexOf(item) == 2 {
        // and here some code to show tabBar.items with index 0
    }
}
```

?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in one of your controllers:

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
```

Comment: Try to put that line inside viewDidAppear of your third tab view controller. Have you properly connected your tabBar viewController with items in storyboard?

Comment: Thank you, man! When I put it inside viewDidAppear it's worked!

Comment: Well, I'm glad to help. Now, if you want, try to tweak it a bit, and put that line inside viewWillAppear/viewDidLoad, so it doesn't blink. Because your user doesn't have to see blank screen, while you move him onto the first tab. I am not sure if this will work, but you can try.

Comment: Can you tell me how I should add UISearchController? Should I add UISearchController as subviews on first tab or it should be in third tab?

Comment: You should add it inside the controller, your would like to be the target controller for displaying results. Anyway, this appears as a new question, so the best would be to create new one.

Comment: Ok, I understand! But can you give me on more tip about blink? I tried put that line in viewWillAppear/viewDidLoad as you say, but when I clicked quickly I see the blank screen.

Comment: It's because if put inside viewDidAppear, it first appears in the original controller, and then it jumps to the first tab. That's why I suggested to put it inside viewWillAppear.

Comment: Hello, @pedrouan, can you give the answer on this question, please [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39487531/how-to-get-rid-of-blink-between-switching-tab-bar-item)