# How to get rid of blink between switching Tab Bar Item

Tags: ios, swift2, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

In my app I should use a several Tab Bar Item with one Controller. To approach this in my Second and Third Tab Bar Item Controllers I use `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0`. As you can see this solution generates blink effect...

[image]

It's happens every time when I choose Third Tab Bar Item.

How to get rid of this blink?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post where exactly you have put that line and also post viewDidAppears, viewWillAppears, viewDidLoads if something related is in. I would track some print()s in these methods so it woúd be better visible why or when are some certain methods skipped/ passed

Comment: I added it in viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear. Also I tried put that line in viewDidLoad, but it's nothing to change

Comment: How is that possible to have both items (first and third) active at the same time?

Comment: I just change the item at third item. Indeed Only active first item.

Comment: I know but as I see two tabs are blue. It is supposed to be only one tab marked active. Or I dont understand that animation, it looks confusing while it is repeating so many times. You could better describe those events- steps by step- like "click on the tab, 1 sec. waiting, then ... " etc.

Comment: In the design of this situation that two tab bar items must be marked. I should searching in first tab. And when I select third, I do this. And in the same time I show that user chose search option. Is it clear for you now?

Comment: Is home view controller containing that search bar originally? What I was thinking until know, was, that you only redirect a user by tapping third tab and that third controller puts you back to home view controller. Then, in your third VC should be nothing except of redirect statement ... = 0

Comment: Yes, you are right! Home view controller containing search bar. When user tapped third I show search bar.

Comment: So I would expect this if set properly: You tap third tab. Third bar will be blue (and the first one will be gray though) just the moment it is being redirected. Then it will show the first Vc and the only blue tab will be the first one with the home icon. Is it like that? When I investigate such situations, I used to switch slow animations mode on (in simulator's main menu). Then it can be easier to find out possible issues. This looks like the first/third view controller dealloc itself from the memory in some occasions.

Comment: 'Is it like that?' Yes, it is. I just to track when was redirect, and light third tab in blue color. I think that view is blinking because third tab has own VC ("SearchViewController") which set up when app is opening. When user chose search tab at first showing "SearchViewController" then happens redirect and then showing "HomeViewController". So question is: how to avoid showing "SearchViewController" at first time?

Comment: **slow animations mode** not working for this case. But in general (like transition between scenes) working well.

Comment: What about to skip that third view controller in this manner: Delete the segue from tabbar controller to third VC and make another segue to the first view controller. You may get new fictive tab that is directing to home either. I haven't tried this option yet.

Comment: Thank you, that you answer me still! I check this and write feedback here.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?